# File being used by another process, despite manually closing handle

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm trying to extract resources out of my dll, and I have the following piece of code, it worked, but it somehow still keep holding on to the handle... I don't think I've done anything wrong with the code below?

```
// example byte data and path
assem.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName).CopyTo(res);
string resPath = "MyApp\\HelloWorld.dll"; // output file
byte[] resData = res.ToArray();           // output data

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(resPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    await fs.WriteAsync(resData, 0, resData.Length);
    references.Add(resourceName);
    log.Info("Updated resource: " + resourceName);
}
```

What else am I missing? This is the 4th iteration of my code after checking out several other posts and suggestions on creating, writing, and closing the stream.

**Edit:**

No, **the dll is not being loaded anywhere else**, the file doesn't exists, after I extracted it, I then try to load the extracted dll further down the line, which is where it complaint about `File being used by another process` (which is basically itself really, but not sure why it couldn't?)... I mean I already set the `FileShare` permission to `ReadWrite` I don't see how others couldn't access it.

I don't have any other anti-virus installed except the `Microsoft Defender` that came OOB with Windows 10.

The flow and interaction is like this, I have the followings:

- Outlook.exe
- MyMainLibrary.dll
- MyPackedLibrary.dll

At start up, `Outlook.exe` trigger a static function in `MyMainLibrary.dll` and extract resources out of `MyPackedLibrary.dll`. So technically, Outlook.exe > MyMainLibrary.dll > extract `HellowWorld.dll` from `MyPackedLibrary.dll`, then Outlook.exe would load `HelloWorld.dll`.

Would `MyMainLibrary.dll` kept the handle opened? Despite it was being called by Outlook.exe?

**Edit2:**

Using `Process Explorer` I could see OUTLOOK.EXE was still holding the handles of my extracted dlls.

Would using a `Thread` cause any of this funny behaviour?

```
// Outlook Startup callback function
private void OnStartupComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // using Thread to not hog up the loading time for Outlook
    new Thread(() =>
    {
    try
        {   
            ...
            // trying to call my static function to extract my stuff here
            MyMainLibraryStuff.ExtractResources("HelloWorld.dll").Wait();
            ...
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {   
            log.Ex(ex);
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: The `fs.Flush()` and `fs.Close()` are unnecessary, by disposing `fs` in a `using` statement those two things happen automatically during the dispose process. Is `HellowWorld.dll` already loaded in your `Modules` window if you check it at the point of the exception? (The module window is under the Debug dropdown menu -> Windows)

Comment: You may also find DLL files are locked by OS processes, for example anti-virus services really don't like executable files being manipulated.

Comment: you can try and use [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or the [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)  to trace which process is trying to access the file.

Comment: You can use `handle.exe` from Sysinternals to find out which process is using your dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Comment: you are inside of a `using(){ }` there is no need to call `fs.Close()` also how large is the file? can you provide a little bite more details ..

Comment: If people are saying `fs.Flush()` and `fs.Close()` are not relevant to the question, and you agree they are not relevant to the question, then [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47537719/edit) them from the question; don't post more irrelevant content.

Comment: So it looks like `WriteAsync` is the reason why it somehow holds the handle... I tried using `File.WriteAllBytes(resPath, resData);` and everything worked... However, I don't want to use `WriteAllBytes` if in the future i need to extract large files. Thoughts?